# Delete data without using form in Laravel

Tags: php, controller

This is my button group that contain View, Edit and **Delete**

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a href="" >View</a>
    <a href="" >Edit</a>
    <a href="{{ action('PhaseController@destroy', $phase->phase_id) }}" >Delete</a>
</div>
```

I have define the action after I click the **Delete** button which is go to the destroy function in the PhaseController with the phase id I want to delete.`

**PhaseController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Developer_user;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Model\Project;
use App\Model\Phase;

class PhaseController extends Controller
{

    public function show($id)
    {
        //After I click the Delete button, It always go to here.
        //How to go to destroy function ?

    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {    
        $deleted_phase = Phase::find($id);
        $deleted_phase->delete();

    }
}
```

However, after I click the Delete button, It always go to the show function but didnt go to the `action('PhaseController@destroy')`.
I can use a form and set the form method to **Delete** to solve this problem. 
But is there anyway to delete it without using Form ?

**UPDATE**
Route.php

[image]

Comment: Can you share router definitions too?

Comment: sure, since i am using Resource route. So, i screenshot my route list for u. I have highlighted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you need to add a custom route. Add the following line to routes/web.php

```
Route::get('phase/destroy/{phaseId}', 'PhaseController@destroy');
```

Url to delete - http://your-domain.com/phase/destroy/1

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a href="" >View</a>
    <a href="" >Edit</a>
    <a href="{{URL::to('/phase/destroy/'.$phase->phase_id)}}" >Delete</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Appreciate your reply sir !!